# SSRS report with "Checkbox"-like feature that adds filters to query

Tags: reporting-services

I have a SQL database  and using SSRS to produce reports.  They are both 2012 version.     The data is well water levels that are record every hour.    Originally I have the report displaying ALL of the data for a user selected well (dropdown list). The user can also select the start and end date (text box)  But the well levels don't change that much every hour unless there is a significant rain/flooding event.    So I want the user to have the option to choose only the noontime values for each day.   Is there a way to have a checkbox that would either 1) change actual query the report is using or 2) include filter that says only display 12:00:00?     The parameter options seems to want to include a date and I only want to filter by time.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the solution for you is to add a parameter to your report to be able to select what information to show with 2 possible values - All / Noon only. Then add a new field / calculated field to your dataset to indicate which ones are noon values. Then use the new parameter to filter the values showed in the report.

Hope it makes sense.

Comment: I think I understand, but some follow up questions.   So if I use the calculated field  its going to have something different for the noon time records than the other records.  A simple as 1 for noon and 0 for all others.   The problem I see is that when I want all  the data I also want the noon values too.  So my new parameter as a filter has to be 1 for the Noon Only and  1 or 0 for All data.  And as I see it for All Data  I really don't need to apply the filter at all.   I am not sure how to accomplish this the way SSRS  applies filters.

Comment: OK I figure out a way based on your suggestion.  I created a calculated field where noon time records where assigned a value of 10 and other hours where  assigned  a value of 1.   Then I created a parameter that had assigned values of 5 for Noon Time Data and 0 for ALL data.   Then I used that new parameter as a filter   where it would check to see if the calculated field was > than the parameter.   This worked out.  Thanks for the help.